# Issue with bundling images in React component library using Rollup

Tags: reactjs, rollup

I am working on a React component library and I am using Rollup as the bundler. But I am having a problem with bundling the images in the library. I have 4 image files that I have used (visaLogo.png, mastercardLogo.png, cardBackgroundVisa.png, and cardBackgroundMasterCard.png). When I run the component libary in Storybook the images load correctly. But when I install the library in another bare React app, only the mastercardLogo.png is shown, the others are missing.

This is my CreditCardForm.tsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./CreditCardForm.css";
import mastercardLogo from "../../../images/mastercardLogo.png";
import visaLogo from "../../../images/visaLogo.png";
import cardBackgroundMasterCard from "../../../images/cardBackgroundMasterCard.png";
import cardBackgroundVisa from "../../../images/cardBackgroundVisa.png";

interface CreditCardFormProps {
  name: string;
  onChangeName: () => void;
  cardNumber: string;
  onChangeCardNumber: () => void;
  expirationDate: string;
  onChangeExpirationDate: () => void;
  cvv: string;
  onChangeCvv: () => void;
  cardType: string;
  onChangeCardType: () => void;
  onSubmit: () => void;
}

const CreditCardForm = (props: CreditCardFormProps) => {
  const [cardType, setCardType] = useState("mastercard");

  const onChangeCardType = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setCardType(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="card-container"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `${
            cardType === "visa"
              ? `url(${cardBackgroundVisa})`
              : `url(${cardBackgroundMasterCard})`
          }`,
        }}
      >
        <div className="card-type">
          <img
            src={cardType === "visa" ? visaLogo : mastercardLogo}
            alt="logo"
            className="logo-style"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="card-number">
          <p>4829 0921 8391 4458</p>
        </div>

        <div className="card-info">
          <div className="card-name">
            <p className="title">Cardholder name</p>
            <p className="info">John Doe</p>
          </div>

          <div className="card-expiration">
            <p className="title">Valid Thru</p>
            <p className="info">01/26</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

//and the form inputs etc...
  
    </>
  );
};

export default CreditCardForm;
```

And this is my rollup.config.js file:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" }; 
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url';
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";


export default [

  {
    input: "src/index.ts", 
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      }, 
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      }, 
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      external(),
      postcss(), 
      url(),
      image(),


    ], 
  },

  
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [
      { file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm", globals: { react: "React" } },
    ],
    plugins: [dts()],
    external: ["react", "react-dom",/\.css$/ ],
  },
];
```

What could be the issue and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `rollup-plugin-copy` plugin. 
Install it and then include it in the plugins section of you config as such: 

     copy({
            targets: [{ src: "src/assets/images", dest: "dist/assets" }],
          }),

In the `src` add the relative path to your images. `Dest` is where they will be included in the bundle created by Rollup. 

This plugin will copy your images in the final bundle, thus making them available when you consumed your package in another project. 

Let me know if it works!

Comment: @Kris I tried it but it did not work, it seems like the three other images are not bundled at all

Comment: Oh, sorry it didn´t help. I read once that the order of the plugins sometimes cause problems. Have you tried reordering them?

Comment: @Kris what order should I follow?

Comment: I am not totally sure, but I would suggest starting with putting the plugins that transform ts and js at the end.